# Sort delimited string alpabetically in single cell

Tags: sorting, excel, vba

I am using the following code to select multiple items from a data validation cell.  It works but I need to sort the entries within the cell so that instead of getting pears, apples, oranges, the result would be apples, oranges, pears, regardless of the order in which the user selects from the dropdown list.

It would also be nice (but not necessary to check for duplicates.  Thanks for the help! Need urgently!

```
Option Explicit
' Developed by Contextures Inc.
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rngDV As Range
Dim oldVal As String
Dim newVal As String
If Target.Count > 1 Then GoTo exitHandler

On Error Resume Next
Set rngDV = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
On Error GoTo exitHandler

If rngDV Is Nothing Then GoTo exitHandler

If Intersect(Target, rngDV) Is Nothing Then
   'do nothing
Else
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  newVal = Target.Value
  Application.Undo
  oldVal = Target.Value
  Target.Value = newVal
  If Target.Column = 3 Then
    If oldVal = "" Then
      'do nothing
      Else
      If newVal = "" Then
      'do nothing
      Else
      Target.Value = oldVal _
        & ", " & newVal
      End If
    End If
  End If
End If

exitHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: You could split the oldVal into an array, find where to insert the newVal into the appropriate position, and then join the array back in to a string.

Answer (score 0):

Without getting into various sorting algorithms, you could temporarily store the values in a range on a worksheet, then using that range, use the `[range].sort()` function in your code to sort the range. Once sorted, you read them back into your `Target.Value` cell, delimiting them as you go.

To remove duplicates, after the range was sorted, but before it is read back into `target.value`, iterate through each cell in the range and delete and shift the values up if the cell is equal to the one below it.